# Make TextBlock Bold only if certain condition is true, via Binding

Tags: wpf, binding

How can I define a `TextBlock` as `FontStyle` is Bold, via a `Binding` to a `bool`?

```
<TextBlock 
   Text="{Binding Name}"
   FontStyle="???">
```

And I'd really like to bind it to

```
public bool NewEpisodesAvailable
{
    get { return _newEpisodesAvailable; }
    set
    {
        _newEpisodesAvailable = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or should my Model property do the translation for me, instead of presenting a `bool` present the `FontStyle` directly?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can achieve that via `DataTrigger` like this:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NewEpisodesAvailable}"
                                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Or you can use [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will convert bool to FontWeight.

```
public class BoolToFontWeightConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock FontWeight="{Binding IsEnable,
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToFontWeightConverter}}"/>
```

***Make sure you declare converter as resource in XAML.***

Comment: Nr1, thx for the details, I'll give them both a try, both concepts are new to me. Thx a lot!

Comment: Brilliant answer highlighting two very useful approaches!

Answer (score 2):

Just implement a converter that converts a bool to your desired font style. Then bind to NewEpisodesAvailable and let your converter return the right value.

Comment: Please help me understand why this hint is rated as not useful. This is a perfect expample to use a small converter. Do you expect full working source code or a hint so that you can continue?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a property that returns the font style in its getter. You can make it return null if your above property is false. Then bind the font style xaml to that property

Comment: well, though your approach will certainly work fine, in general case it won't align nicely with MVVM, because font and alike are usually a responsibility of the view, so you will have to introduce a kind of proxy to keep view-related properties separated from the model - view model may be handy for that. In general more coding will be required, since changing underlying model property should affect the view-specific bound property.

Answer (score 1):

Use trigger in this case.

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NewEpisodesAvailable}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

Article on CodeProject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/522041/Triggers-in-WPF